# How to create the built-in function count, without using it. python

Tags: python, function, count, built-in

I would like to get the exact same result as this code:

```
def histogram(s):
    d = {}

    for w in s: 
        d[w] = s.count(w)

    for k in sorted(d):
        print (k + ': ' + str(d[k]))
```

But without using any built-in functions. I only want to use len() and range() and chr() and ord().

The result of this program when typing in Mississippi is:

```
M: 1
i: 4
p: 2
s: 4
```

To clear it all upp!

Write a function histogram(s) that takes a string as a parameter and
returns a list with a histogram over the numbers of characters.

And a function histprint should be implemented, that takes a list as 
the function histogram(s) have returned and writes a table on the screen, containing all the characters that was in the string. The result should look like:

```
>>> h=histogram('Mississippi') 
>>> histprint(h) 
M: 1 
i: 4 
p: 2 
s: 4
```

NO built-in functions!

Comment: have you looked into https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter ?

Comment: Yes, but they only explain the built-in function (count). I want the same result but without the count()

Answer (score 1):

`count` and `Counter` are the ways to go but the following should work fine too.

```
my = "stackoverflow"
d={}
for l in my:
        d[l] = d.get(l,0) + 1 
print d

{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'k': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 2, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'w': 1, 'v': 1}
```

Comment: That´s one way, but i am thinking even more simpler. And NO built-in funktions at all! ;)

Comment: Oh! not even `get()` eh ? But then `len()` `range()`  `chr()` `ord()` are also built in functions :P

Comment: Exactly! Only the ones I said:

len()
range()
chr()
ord()

Comment: Not so fimiliar with try and except :/

Comment: @sagarchalise Can you explain why `try` and `except` is necessary here ? In above code ?

Comment: @d-coder OP says he wants to avoid `get` and your answer seems legit so I edited.

Comment: @sagarchalise Actually he means `get` should not be used either because it is also in built function. I really don't follow how `try` and `except` will help him or this code to do any better than what it actually does.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to avoid any builtins functions as well as methods such as get. You can use `try` `catch` which is same as what @d-coder answered.

Basically you could do:

```
def histogram(word):
    counter = {}
    for char in word:
        try:
            counter[char] = counter[char] + 1
        except KeyError:
            counter[char] = 1
    return counter

def histprint(h):
    for k in h:
        print k, h[k]
```

This answer is not different from above and is only removing `get` with ``` try``except ```.

Also [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is not a builtin function but a datatype available for particularly this kind of purpose AFAIK.

Comment: Tanks! Looks good, but how do i put it in a funtion so i can typ in any word and not just use Mississippi?

Comment: @PatrikFernberg made a function as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a dictionary of letters, and counting the frequency of letters in the word.

- First, create a dictionary of letters, initialized by zero.

> ```
> import string
> d= dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_letters, 0) 
> #d= dict(zip(string.ascii_letters, [0]*52))  # string.ascii_letters: should give you a list of  alphabets (UPPER case,lower case).
> ```

Note: Check the comments

```
Output:
```

> ```
> {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'B': 0, 'E': 0, 'D': 0, 'G': 0, 'F': 0, 'I': 0, 'H': 0, 'K': 0, 'J': 0, 'M': 0, >'L': 0, 'O': 0, 'N': 0, 'Q': 0, 'P':
> ```
>
> 0, 'S': 0, 'R': 0, 'U': 0, 'T': 0, 'W': 0, 'V': 0, 'Y': 0, 'X': 0,
>   'Z': 0, 'a': 0, 'c': 0, 'b': 0, 'e': 0, 'd': 0, 'g': 0, 'f': 0, 'i':
>   0, 'h': 0, 'k': 0, 'j': 0, 'm': 0, 'l': 0, 'o': 0, 'n': 0, 'q': 0,
>   'p': 0, 's': 0, 'r': 0, 'u': 0, 't': 0, 'w': 0, 'v': 0, 'y': 0, 'x':
>   0, 'z': 0}

- Then, go through every character and add `+1` whenever you find it.

> ```
> w= "Mississippi"
> for x in list(w):
>   d[x]+=1
>
> l= {}
> for (key, value) in d.iteritems():
>   if value>0:
>     print key:value
> ```

Output:

> ```
> M : 1
> i : 4
> p : 2
> s : 4
> ```

So your function would be:

```
def histprint(w):
  d= dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_letters, 0)

  for x in list(w):
    d[x]+=1

  l= {}
  for (key, value) in d.iteritems():
    if value>0:
      print key,':',value


histprint("Mississippi")
```

If you are counting the characters, and you don't distinguish between uppercase and lower case (i.e: You assume that `M` and `m` refers to same character, and not to Upper 'M' or lower 'm')

Your algorithm would look like:

```
import string

def histprint(w):
  d= dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)

  for x in list(w.lower()):
    d[x]+=1

  l= {}
  for (key, value) in d.iteritems():
    if value>0:
      print key,':',value


histprint("Mississippi")
```

Comment: I have a feeling this doesn't meet the OP's requirements, but I'll point out that `d= dict(zip(string.ascii_letters, [0]*52))` - could just be written as `d = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_letters, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def histogram(s):
    d = {}    
    for i in s:
        try:
            d[i] += 1
        except KeyError:
            d[i] = 1
    # Do you want to implement sorting also without inbuilt method ?
    # Not added sorting here ! `sorted(d)` will give the sorted keys.
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        print "{} : {}".format(k, v)
```

Comment: Yes i want to implement sorting as well.

Comment: Sorting is a trivial thing. I think that you can handle. Pick insertion sort for your case. It's best for small set.